# Slice the rows with the earliest datetime

Tags: r, dplyr, slice

I have a dataframe and I want to filter only rows that corresponds to the earliest datetime. The following is my dataframe:

```
library(lubridate)
df<-data.frame(ID=rep(1:2,5:6),DATETIME_OF_PROCEDURE=rep(c(ymd_hms("2013-03-16 03:00:42"),
                                                           ymd_hms("2013-02-12 08:00:42"),
                                                           ymd_hms("2014-06-19 01:00:42"),
                                                           ymd_hms("2014-01-22 01:00:42"),
                                                           ymd_hms("2014-06-12 02:00:40")),
                                                         c(3,2,2,2,2)))
```

I would like to get:

```
#     > df
#    ID DATETIME_OF_PROCEDURE
# 1   1   2013-02-12 16:00:42
# 2   1   2013-02-12 16:00:42
# 3   2   2014-01-22 09:00:42
# 4   2   2014-01-22 09:00:42
```

I tried the following but it gives an empty dataframe.

```
df %>% 
  arrange(DATETIME_OF_PROCEDURE) %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>%
  slice(min(DATETIME_OF_PROCEDURE))
```

I also tried `slice(first(DATETIME_OF_PROCEDURE))` but again, it wouldn't work.

Comment: The correct syntax would be `df %>% arrange(DATETIME_OF_PROCEDURE) %>% group_by(ID) %>% slice(1L)` but `slice` will not capture ties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df %>% 
    group_by(ID) %>% 
    filter(DATETIME_OF_PROCEDURE == min(DATETIME_OF_PROCEDURE))
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you already `arrange`, `slice(1)` works fine:

```
df %>% 
  arrange(DATETIME_OF_PROCEDURE) %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>%
  slice(1)
```

Other use `which.min`, since `filter` takes indices:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>%
  slice(which.min(DATETIME_OF_PROCEDURE))
```

Be careful of ties in your data. Use `filter` if you want to retain all ties.

Both return the same:

> ```
> Source: local data frame [2 x 2]
> Groups: ID [2]
>
>      ID DATETIME_OF_PROCEDURE
>   <int>                <dttm>
> 1     1   2013-02-12 09:00:42
> 2     2   2014-01-22 02:00:42
> ```